# How to get a reference to a function that doesn't take parameters in F#?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, memoization, f#-3.0

I sometimes have the need to get the function itself, not the value, of a zero-parameter function in F#, for instance for memoization. I.e., I have this:

```
let memoize (f: 'a -> 'b) =
    let dict = new Dictionary<'a, 'b>()
    let memoizedFunc (input: 'a) =
        match dict.TryGetValue(input) with
        | true, x -> x
        | false, _ ->
            let answer = f input
            dict.Add(input, answer)
            answer
    memoizedFunc
```

and this works perfectly, but now I have the following function:

```
let private getDataSlowOperation =
    // implementation
```

and when I try to memoize that, it gives a type mismatch (essentially the mismatch between the return type of `getDataSlowOperation` and the `'a` type). I can solve this by changing the function as follows:

```
let private getDataSlowOperation bogus =
    // implementation
```

Now this works, but it seems odd to have to change the function signature to get memoization to work:

```
let memoGetDataSlowOperation = memoize getDataSlowOperation
```

I've experimented with inline `fun` declarations, but this creates, of course, a new anonymous function and the memoization doesn't work with that. Any ideas how to resolve this? Any keyword / operator I've forgotten about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you defined is not a function, it's just a value.

In order to define it as a function you can write this:

```
let private getDataSlowOperation() =
    // implementation
```

**UPDATE**

To summarize the discussion:

- This is the right way to write it as a function, however the code would still not work but that's a different problem.
- The code would fail at runtime because `()` is compiled to `null` and by using a Dictionary you can't use `null` for the Key. You can use a Map instead.
- John pointed out that memoization for functions without parameters makes no sense, I agree.
- Still, if you use a Dictionary for functions with parameters you will run into the same problem with values that are compiled to `null`, ie: `None`

Comment: See! I knew I was missing the obvious! Thanks. (PS: I thought even data were functions, as in "everything is a function" in F#).

Comment: I would say every function is a value in F# but the opposite is not true.

Comment: Well, Alonzo Church, founder of Lambda calculus, "formalized every mathematical construct using the most essential mathematical concept, a function" (p31, Real World Functional Programming, T. Petricek).

Comment: In pure FP it's another story, you don't need to differentiate between let f = something and let f() = something   since something cannot have side-effects.

Comment: Actually, after some testing, I found that the solution you provided does *not* work: it causes `'a` to be `null`, causing errors with `TryGetValue`.

Comment: Yes, it does. However, I understand the error and I think I can work around it (or I'll ask a different question).

Comment: I see, the problem is you need to handle the case where the key is unit in your memoize function (or any other value that is compiled as null). Otherwise consider defining a memoize for each number of parameters (memoize0, memoize1, memoize2, ... ) . Have a look at this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsyme/archive/2007/05/31/a-sample-of-the-memoization-pattern-in-f.aspx

Comment: But why are you trying to memoize this at all.  You have a value which gets calculated once - if you move it to the top level, the compiler will automatically memoize it by storing the value for you.

Comment: @John: this is F#, a functional language, a let binding is evaluated again when it is called again. So, when the operation behind the let binding is lengthy, you can solve that by memoizing. Maybe I do something wrong or misunderstand something, but it did speed up the program multifold, so the memoization clearly helped. Gustavo: thanks for the update. Note, however, that using a map is excruciatingly slow (as your link explains), there are better solutions, like an empty class wrapper.

Comment: @Abel Indeed Map might be slow. About let bindings, if you write let memoized = myFunction() the function is evaluated once, after that you may call memoized as many times as you want. It's the same as writing let memoized = memoize myFunction

Comment: @Abel - you are incorrect - run this code - `let res = printfn "hi";1; printfn "%i" res; printfn "%i" (res+res);`  This only will print hi once - i.e. the compiler has done memoization for you.

Comment: @john / Gustavo, what you are saying is correct, of course, I think what confused me was that this method was scoped. The profiler clearly showed the load-function being run multiple times and after memoization, the performance hit was gone.